# What is the simplified Big O notation of O(4^251267)

Tags: big-o

I have a doubt wether it is O(4^n) or O(1) since it's a constant.

Comment: is 251267 a variable number (of elements or whatever)? Then it is O(4^n). If it is a fix number 4^251267 is a constant so it is O(1)

Comment: You don't give us enough details : what does 251267 correspond to ? Is taht a length of an array, a string, ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a constant independent of input length, thus O(1).